# How to get GWT Plugin running with Grails?

Tags: gwt, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

When using the [grails GWT plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gwt) I have trouble to get my dependencies refreshed.

I inserted

```
compile ":gwt:0.8"
```

into my BuildConfig.groovy and run: grails refresh-dependencies. My Grails version is 2.3M1.

The process stopps with the following error. How do I have to fix that?

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.0.M1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
Gwt version 2.5.0 requested, downloading required dependencies
| Error Error loading event script from file [/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS-3.3M1-  JUNO-4.2.2/testg23/target/work/plugins/gwt-0.8/scripts/_Events.groovy] No such property: resolveEngine for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.AetherDependencyManager (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Compiling 17 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS-3.3M1-JUNO-4.2.2/testg23/target/work/plugins/gwt-0.8/src/java/grails/plugins/gwt/client/GwtActionService.java:3: error: package com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc does not exist
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;

/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS-3.3M1-JUNO-4.2.2/testg23/target/work/plugins/gwt-0.8/src/java/grails/plugins/gwt/client/GwtActionService.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public interface GwtActionService extends RemoteService {

symbol: class RemoteService
/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS-3.3M1-JUNO-4.2.2/testg23/target/work/plugins/gwt-0.8/src/java/grails/plugins/gwt/client/GwtActionServiceAsync.java:3: error: package com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc does not exist
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS-3.3M1-JUNO-4.2.2/testg23/target/work/plugins/gwt-  0.8/src/java/grails/plugins/gwt/client/GwtActionServiceAsync.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
void execute(Action action, AsyncCallback callback);

symbol: class AsyncCallback
location: interface GwtActionServiceAsync
Note: /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS-3.3M1-JUNO-4.2.2/testg23/target/work/plugins/gwt-0.8/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/gwt/XMLJUnitResultFormatter.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the gwt plugin with success. Steps:

- Installed Grails 2.3.0.M1, created `GRAILS_HOME`.
- Installed GWT SDK
- Created env var `GWT_HOME` pointing to the gwt folder.
- Created a new project
- Changed BuildConfig.groovy, adding the dependency `compile ":gwt:0.8"`
- Runned the command `grails compile --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: Did you runned grails commands outside the IDE to see if it works? Try cleaning `target/work` before the compile.

Comment: What do you mean by "Created env var GWT_HOME pointing to the gwt folder." where? how?

Comment: You need to manually install the [GWT SDK](http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html) and create the GWT_HOME like you do with GRAILS_HOME.

Comment: Wehre so Youssef gwt home?

Answer (score 0):

The default dependency resolution engine is changed to [Aether](http://eclipse.org/aether/) in Grails 2.3.M1 (hence forth).
Since this is a milestone version there might be some hickups initially. If you want to fall back to `maven` or `ivy` as the dependency resolver, use

`grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy`

Have a look at [What's New in Grails 2.3.](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.M1/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew23)

Comment: I use grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" but it gave me the error above.

Comment: Then I would suggest to follow the thumb rule. `grails clean && grails compile`. If required, clean `.grails/2.3.0.M1/projects/yourProject` manually. Moreover, I see logs related to Aether in contradiction to above setting?

Comment: I know that the log shows Aether but I did set maven as the resolver.

Comment: You need to clean GGTS' targets as well and try.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your target in workspace you used for GGTS project.